# Where does logstash write its logs when "codec => rubydebug"?

Tags: debugging, printing, logstash, stdout, codec

I've just installed latest version of logstash on my mac and tried this:

```
logstash -e 'input { stdin { } } output { stdout { codec => rubydebug } }'
```

This command is from internet guide and it says it will print some messages, my question is, does this command store the log into any file, or it's just tries to print formatted json strings as I can see from screen print?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"codec => rubydebug" prints on screen only. Here in your script logstash is expecting user to provide some input and whatever  is provided will be printed back to the screen. If you want to store your output to any file use "file" output option.